# Toggle Button JavaScript Code Not Working in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want to ask help with the comment section down below of the JavaScript Code. I want to work the toggle button / hamburger button but it does not work because addEventListener is not required for ReactJS. What code must be encoded? Thank you.

I am doing a Traversy Media Tutorial using Tailwind CSS. I want to use React as framework because of its composable component feature and efficiency to use.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../images/logo.svg';

// const btn = document.getElementById('menu-btn')
// const nav = document.getElementById('menu')

// btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
//   btn.classList.toggle('open')
//   nav.classList.toggle('flex')
//   nav.classList.toggle('hidden')
// })

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className='relative container mx-auto p-6'>
        {/* Flex Container */}
        <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
          {/* Logo */}
          <div className='pt-2'>
            <img src={logo} alt='logo.svg'></img>
          </div>

          {/* Menu Items */}
          <div className='hidden space-x-6 md:flex'>
            <a href='/' className='hover:text-darkGrayishBlue'>
              Pricing
            </a>
            <a href='/' className='hover:text-darkGrayishBlue'>
              Product
            </a>
            <a href='/' className='hover:text-darkGrayishBlue'>
              About Us
            </a>
            <a href='/' className='hover:text-darkGrayishBlue'>
              Careers
            </a>
            <a href='/' className='hover:text-darkGrayishBlue'>
              Community
            </a>
          </div>

          {/* Button */}
          <div>
            <a
              href='/'
              className='hidden p-3 px-6 pt-2 text-white bg-brightRed rounded-full baseline hover:bg-brightRedLight md:block'
            >
              Get Started
            </a>
          </div>

          {/* Hambuger Icon */}
          <button
            id='menu-btn'
            className='block hamburger md:hidden focus:outline-none'
          >
            <span className='hamburger-top'></span>
            <span className='hamburger-middle'></span>
            <span className='hamburger-bottom'></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        {/* Mobile Menu */}
        <div className='md:hidden'>
          <div
            id='menu'
            className='absolute flex-col items-center hidden self-end  py-8 mt-10 space-y-6 font-bold bg-white sm:w-auto sm:self-center left-6 right-6 drop-shadow-md'
          >
            <a href='/'>Pricing</a>
            <a href='/'>Product</a>
            <a href='/'>About</a>
            <a href='/'>Careers</a>
            <a href='/'>Community</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is define an `open` state and a click listener for the button.
Then change the class of the objects based on the `open` flag:

````
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../images/logo.svg';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleMenuClick = () => {
    setOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className='relative container mx-auto p-6'>
        {/* Flex Container */}
        <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>

          {/* ... */}

          {/* Hambuger Icon */}
          <button
            id='menu-btn'
            className={`block hamburger md:hidden focus:outline-none ${
              open && 'open'
            }`}
            onClick={() => handleMenuClick()}
          >
            <span className='hamburger-top'></span>
            <span className='hamburger-middle'></span>
            <span className='hamburger-bottom'></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        {/* Mobile Menu */}
        <div className='md:hidden'>
          <div
            id='menu'
            className={`absolute flex-col items-center hidden self-end  py-8 mt-10 space-y-6 font-bold bg-white sm:w-auto sm:self-center left-6 right-6 drop-shadow-md ${
              open ? 'flex' : 'hidden'
            }`}
          >
            <a href='/'>Pricing</a>
            <a href='/'>Product</a>
            <a href='/'>About</a>
            <a href='/'>Careers</a>
            <a href='/'>Community</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the event handling where you define your button. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
 <button
            id='menu-btn'
            className='block hamburger md:hidden focus:outline-none'
            onClick={doAction}>
          >
```

[Official documentation regarding event handling in react.](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)